# Connecting Azure Fabric to on-prem SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, fabric

What IP addresses need whitelisting to connect Azure Fabric to an on-prem SQL Server via Dataflow Gen 2 or Copy pipelines?

Comment: None - what you ask is essentially how to expose your database to the public internet. You need to either use a VPN (VNet) or a data gateway [as the docs explain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/security/security-overview#data-gateway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the on-prem gateway instead of opening ports.

> Data Factory for Microsoft Fabric is a powerful cloud-based data integration service that allows you to create, schedule, and manage workflows for various data sources. In scenarios where your data sources are located on-premises, Microsoft provides the On-Premises Data Gateway to securely bridge the gap between your on-premises environment and the cloud. This document guides you through the process of accessing on-premises data sources within Data Factory for Microsoft Fabric using the On-Premises Data Gateway.

[How to access on-premises data sources in Data Factory for Microsoft Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-factory/how-to-access-on-premises-data)